# Actionscript quiz game using adobe animate

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi im new to actionscript and I and my classmates are making a quiz game using adobe animate. What i want to happen is when a user tap the checkbutton the checkbutton will check if the the answer that the user inputted in the textbox is correct or wrong. When the Answer matched the correct answer it will go to the next page which is frame3 and when it is wrong it will only stay in its currentframe. the problem is even when the answer that is inputted is correct and it matched with the right answer it wont proceed to the other frame it will always stay in its currentframe, as if like the
`if(textbox.text == "correctanswer")` is ignored. 
I hope you can help me :) Thanks in Advance

```
checkbutton_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopFromFrame_2);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopFromFrame_2(event:MouseEvent)
{
    if(textbox.text == "correctanswer"){
        gotoAndStop(3);
      }else{
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: trace("-"+textbox.text+"-"); and see maybe some space is block equal situation.

Comment: Code can only respond to things that exist on that frame. Keep **everything** (code / MovieClips / etc) on frame 1. If you must show a different frame then **don't move stage**, instead move some other MC. So have a big (stage-size) one that holds all stuff of frame 2 & frame 3. Call it `contentMC`. Then you say `contentMC.gotoAndStop(3);`. This will fix your problem & solve later issues.

Comment: So you have a text box that is supposed to say "correctanswer"? Is that a box the user is supposed to see? If so, why is there no space between "correct" and "answer"? Like "Correct Answer"? I ask because I suspect you are misunderstanding how strings or variables in general work.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Sorry if my english are bad and you dont understand it well. @NealDavis the "correctanswer" is where you put the right answer. for example the question is where is newyork the right answer is America right? so the code will be if(textbox.text == "America") sorry if im bad at explaining things. Im just a student still learning :) anyways i try another way and it is now okay so dont bother anymore but I appreciate the help from you guys take you and Godbless :)

Comment: @DustineJohnViado oh good job. Your English is great. Your example cleared it up perfectly.